# how to prove $x+n+a = \sqrt{ax + (n+a)^2 + x \sqrt{a (x+n) + (n+a)^2 + (x+n)\sqrt{ 1 + \dots}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

what strategies can I employ to show that the following identity holds for $a , x \ge 0$?
$$x+n+a = \sqrt{ax + (n+a)^2 + x \sqrt{a (x+n) + (n+a)^2 + (x+n)\sqrt{  1 + \dots}}}$$

The only way I can think if of induction, because by squaring I seem to get the result for $(x+n) + n + a$ (which is highly suggestive) but I don't know how to begin with base case. Probably the duplicate exists. If so, please give links in comments. The problem is taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan#Attention_towards_mathematics).

Comment: Do you have an expression for the common term $X_n+Y_n$ in $\sqrt{X_0+Y_0\sqrt{X_1+Y_1\sqrt{\dots}}}$?

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't see the pattern here?  For the life of me, I don't know how to continue the $\ldots$'s.

Comment: no, the other one would be me ... @abiessu what do you mean by common term?

Comment: We're all talking about the same thing, by "common term" I am referring to the pattern.  So far, it doesn't appear to me that there is one...

Comment: I think the $\sqrt{1 + \ldots}$ is wrong. The correct version seems to be $\sqrt{\ldots}$. In which case, simply replace $x$ with $x+n$ then $x+2n$ etc. for each nested root (for the expression).

Comment: @FengyangWang you mean $x+n+a = \sqrt{ax + (n+a)^2 + x \sqrt{a (x+n) + (n+a)^2 + (x+n)\sqrt{   \dots}}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the general form of Ramanajuan's famous nested radical.

$(x+n+a)^2 = (ax+(n+a)^2+x(x+2n+a)$
$(x+n+a) = \sqrt{ax+(n+a)^2+x(x+2n+a)}$

The $x+2n+a = \sqrt{a(x+n)+(n+a)^2+(x+n)((x+n)+2n+a)}$

Etc. Replacing $x+kn+a$ repeatedly by rewriting it.

Comment: Convergence must be established.

Comment: I'll take it yes for an answer. I'll think about convergence later.